# Do the Wonka Bars in the movie Charlie and the Chocolate Factory have peanut butter in them?

Tags: charlie-and-the-chocolate-factory

The Wonka bar they showed Agustus eating appeared to have peanut butter in it. Maybe it was to demonstrate his point of view when he said he tasted something that was not chocolate and was wondering if it was peanut butter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think not. When Charlie ate his, it looked like only chocolate. I think when they showed the Wonka bar Agustus was eating with peanut butter in it, they were demonstrating his thought process. He said he bit into something and it tasted like something that was not chocolate. He was wondering if it was peanut butter. Then he found that what he actually bit into was the golden ticket after he saw that he bit off a corner of the ticket.

Answer (score 1):

The bars seen on screen in [*Charlie and the Chocolate Factory (2005)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlie_and_the_Chocolate_Factory_(film)) include the 'Whipple-Scrumptious Fudgemallow Delight', 'Chilly Chocolate Creme', 'Triple Dazzle Caramel' and 'Nutty Crunch Surprise' and while Gloot is seen *eating* a Nutty Crunch Surprise [when we see him with the ticket](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FHKOkVVyAVM), it's not made clear whether this is the flavour he found the ticket in.

Charlie's ticket is [found in a Fudgemallow](https://youtu.be/KR8PscR6N2s?t=56) but any of the flavours below (including the nut one) could contain the golden ticket, as demonstrated by the gold "WIN A TRIP TO WONKA'S CHOCOLATE FACTORY" stamp in the corner of each bar wrapper).

[image]

It's worthwhile noting that in the original *[Willy Wonka & the Chocolate Factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Willy_Wonka_%26_the_Chocolate_Factory) (1971)* Charlie opens a chocolate bar whose ingredients are just "*Milk Chocolate with vanillin, an artificial flavoring*".

[image]

Comment: That's like saying:  "Key lime pie; ingredients: pie."